# Solution on ElementNotVisibleException in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, exception

I need to click on a link which displays a popup. But, I'm receiving the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 15.12 seconds

Here is the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account information")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Change Password")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("changeEmail")).click();
```

and html:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 frmmargin" ng-show="!externalUser && isextranalUser==true">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<p>
<a ng-click="hidesuccessmsg()" data-toggle="modal" target="-self" href="#changeEmail">Change Password</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Hi Lakshmi, welcome to SQA. Is your question answered by this: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2084/cant-click-this-checkbox-using-webdriver-selenium-elementnotvisibleexcepti

Comment: @Lakshmi Priya, Error is thrown on which line? If the error is thrown after popup appears, then try [Popup Handling](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/). If the error is thrown before the popup appears then try using **Waits**.

Comment: @Waits, It's working fine with partiallinkText

Comment: It's working fine with partiallinkText

Comment: I was able to solve by using partial link text @FindBy(partialLinkText="Change") public WebElement lnk_ChangePswd;

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use any of the below `wait` methods. You may find success with any of these 3 methods, but it is always a good practice to use `Explicit Wait` as you are instructing the web driver to specifically look for what you need, instead of blindly waiting till the entire DOM gets loaded.

**Explicit Wait:** (Most Preferred)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("elementID")));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("elementID")));
```

**Implicit Wait:**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Sleep:** (Try to avoid this unless absolutely necessary)

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Note: It'll be more helpful if you can provide the link you are trying to test, so that we can help you with a more accurate answer.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you gave (username : priya.testing@gmail.com, password : password) are correct? I'm getting `Invalid username and password` error when I use them.

Comment: Logging in thru Google+ is also not working with your credentials, even with the new e-mail id you gave (priya.veritis@gmail.com).

Comment: For priya.veritis@gmail.com using Google+ I'm recieving `The email and password you entered don't match.` error. Password I used - password.

Comment: Can you login with Email ---  laya.indugula@gmail.com, password is password ? Thanks for your patience

Comment: This worked and I'm in. I'll try and let you know if I'm able to resolve your issue.

Comment: Do you want to change password using the `Change Password` link in `Account Information` tab?

Comment: I need to check through selenium, but it's not at all opening the pop up if we click through script

Comment: @Lakshmipriya were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: No, i couldn't able to solve this issue

Comment: I was able to solve by using partial link text
 @FindBy(partialLinkText="Change")
  public WebElement lnk_ChangePswd;

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accountinformation")).isDisplayed())
    {
    System.out.println("Displayed");
    }
else
{
  System.out.println("fail");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply Sameer, it's displaying fail.
i used assertion and tried with all possible locators xpath, cssselector, linkText, but it's not working

Comment: have u added implicitwait ?

Comment: yes i added before if condition

Comment: try with partial link text or by tagname

Comment: I tried with partial link text, but not working

Comment: hi   Lakshmi priya i tried with ur html by link text it is working fine...which browser you are using?

Comment: i'm using Mozilla FireFox

Comment: Sameer, could you please edit this answer to give more context? There's clearly more going on, given that Lakshmi isn't having any luck with your suggestion.

Comment: @Lakshmi priyai also tried with firefox itself its working fine, i think the issue is not related to coding might be the framework structure you are using like TestNg.